# Emacs org-mode, agenda view, discover overlapping tasks

Tags: org-mode

If I have following scheduled items in my org file:

```
** meeting a

   SCHEDULED: <2015-11-12 Thu 21:00-23:00>

** meeting b

   SCHEDULED: <2015-11-12 Thu 22:00-23:00>
```

which generates following lines in the agenda view:

```
  annotations:21:00-23:00 Scheduled:  meeting a

  annotations:22:00-23:00 Scheduled:  meeting b
```

How can highlight overlapping items like these? I thought that `v c` in the agenda view would show them, but no. The case above is quite obvious, but in the case of a recurring task, it would not be feasible to review all items.

Comment: Does the function `org-agenda-toggle-time-grid` or the variables `org-agenda-use-time-grid` and `org-agenda-time-grid` help visualize the overlapping schedules?  http://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-commands.html

Comment: @lawlist: nope. Specially with recurring tasks which have different time intervals, that can be tough. I'd need a clear indication that a task recurring each 11 days and a task recurring each 13 will overlap in 143 days.

Comment: AFAICS highlighting of overlapping of schedules is not yet implemented. As a workaround you possibly could convert the schedules to clock intervals like `CLOCK: [2015-11-12 Thu 21:00]-[2015-11-12 Thu 23:00]` and then use `v c`.

Comment: Yes I'd do that then. But it should be -- instead of -, at least in my installation. Otherwise, you get a dangling clock.

Comment: You are right that it should be `--` instead of `-`.  Sorry for that irritation.